# Ansible: 'shell' not executing

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to run a shell command to install a package downloaded from my local Artifactory repository, as I don't have access to download it straight from the internet.

When I run the command directly on the node as such

```
rpm -ivh kubectl-1.1.1.x86_64.rpm --nodigest --nofiledigest
```

It works perfectly.

But then put in Ansible playbook as such

```yaml
- name: Install Kubectl
  shell: rpm -ivh kubectl-1.1.1.x86_64.rpm --nodigest --nofiledigest
```

Nothing happens.

It doesn't error.. It just doesn't install.

I've tried the `command` and `ansible.builtin.shell` module as well, but nothing works.

Is there a way to do this please?

Comment: It would help if you were to [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the result of this task and then display the result in a subsequent `debug` task; this might give us some idea what's going on.

Comment: Since you are going to install an RPM, the Ansible [`yum`](https://docs.ansible.comansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html) module might be a better choice.

Comment: Just for your record, `ansible.builtin.shell` is the FQCN (Fully Qualified Collection Name) of the `shell` (short name) module since base collections are packaged separatly in ansible 2.10. Both names can be used and point to the exact same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different topics in your question.

Regarding

> to install a package downloaded from my local Artifactory repository, as I don't have access to download it straight from the internet.

you can use different approaches.

**1. Direct download**

```yaml
- name: Make sure package becomes installed from internal repository
  yum:
    name: https://{{ REPOSITORY_URL }}/artifactory/kube/kubectl-{{ KUBE_VERSION }}.x86_64.rpm
    state: present
```

**2. Configure local repository**

The next one is to provide a `.repo` template file like

```
[KUBE]
name = Kubectl - $basearch
baseurl = https://{{ REPOSITORY_URL }}/artifactory/kube/
username = {{ API_USER }}
password = {{ API_KEY }}
sslverify = 1
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-KUBE
```

and to perform

```yaml
- name: Make sure package becomes installed from internal repository
  yum:
    name: kubectl
    state: present
```

This is possible because JFrog Artifactory can provide local RPM repositories if configured correctly. For more information you research the documentation there since it is almost only about proper configuration.

Regarding

> Nothing happens. It doesn't error.. It just doesn't install.

you can use several task to split up your steps, make them idempotent and get an better insight how they are working.

**3. `shell`, `rpm` and `debug`**

```yaml
- name: Make sure destination folder for package download (/opt/packages) exists
  file:
    path: "/opt/packages/"
    state: directory

- name: Download RPM to remote hosts
  get_url:
    url: "https://{{ REPOSTORY_URL }}/artifactory/kube/kubectl-{{ KUBE_VERSION }}.x86_64.rpm"
    dest: "/opt/packages/kubectl-{{ KUBE_VERSION }}.x86_64.rpm"
 
- name: Check package content
  shell:
    cmd: "rpm -qlp /opt/packages/kubectl-{{ KUBE_VERSION }}.x86_64.rpm"
  register: rpm_qlp

- name: STDOUT rpm_qlp
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ rpm_qlp.stdout.split('\n')[:-1] }}"

- name: Install RPM using 'command: rpm -ivh'
  shell:
    cmd: "rpm -ivh /opt/packages/kubectl-{{ KUBE_VERSION }}.x86_64.rpm"
  register: rpm_ivh

- name: STDOUT rpm_ivh
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ rpm_ivh.stdout.split('\n')[:-1] }}"
```

Depending on the RPM package, environment and configuration, all may just work good.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `command` module and register the output i use it to install oci8 by pecl for oracle database on linux